# Can yeoman tests be run in parallel?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

We just hit an issue with `yeoman-generator` tests when they would pass when run in isolation but fail when run in parallel with other tests.

Specifically, we call `require('yeoman-generator').test.run()` to run the generator and then use `require('yeoman-generator').assert.file` to check that the correct files were generated, which is what the [documentation](http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html) says. However, the `assert` would sometimes fail saying the files don't exist.

How does the interaction between `test.run()` and `assert.file` work? Where are the files written? Is is a global variable / temp file that is always the same and therefore can be overwritten by other tests running at the same time?

This is [the test](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/__tests__/generator-android-test.js), and an example of a [failing build](https://travis-ci.org/facebook/react-native/jobs/81832471).

There's a github issue with [detailed discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2974) and here's a discussion on how the tests [suddenly started passing](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2981) when run in isolation.

We are using the [Jest testing framework](http://facebook.github.io/jest/) which runs tests in parallel.

Comment: Looks like run() creates a new RunContext with a temp path: https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/test/run-context.js#L35

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Yeoman tests can't be run in parallel.

`require('yeoman-generator').test.run()` does create a temp directory but then changes the **current working directory** to that directory. This interferes with other tests that also rely on the CWD and therefore the Yeoman tests can't be run in parallel with other tests.

Relevant comment in [`run-context.js`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/test/run-context.js#L123) and [`process.chdir`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/test/helpers.js#L95) in `helpers.js`.

Comment: That's not totally true. Tests just cannot run in parallel in the same process. The CWD behavior you're having is something we were forced to add into Yeoman because of people following less than ideal development practices. Maybe we should reconsider it some day; feel free to open an issue to discuss it.